# Could the equivalence classes in the construction of quotient group be the orbits of some group action?

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$, $S\le G$, the $G/S$ is the collection of all left cosets, $gS$ for all $g\in G$.  And These cosets partition $G$. Given that the orbits of any group action on $G$ also partition $G$, could there be a group action on $G$ the collection of the orbits is identical to the collection of the left cosets of $S$?

Comment: Yes. It's $S$ acting on $G$ by right multiplication.

Comment: It would be the action of $S$ on $G$ with the group product.

Comment: The group $S$ acting by multiplication from the right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan@Javier@Jyrki Lahtonen: Thank you all.